# Manually alter/change displayed time and date sent Outlook email? Alter headers date time sent in code Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2010, microsoft-outlook-2013, timestamp, source-code, microsoft-edge-devtools

In Gmail I can go in using inspect and dev tools and epoch converter then go through SMTP and alter the date and time stamps, backdate emails, send custom fillable dynamic emails.

I can’t find anything that will work like that for Outlook emails.

I have the older 2010/13 version and the newer Outlook exchange. There has to be a way to do the equivalent to Gmail.

Go in and edit the time and date(not alter the format-the actual displayed time) stylize email to match email client and edit/input the source code, as well Gmail I can make it so the other/user/receiver can’t see or change the data.

There has to be some converter, dev plug-in or something for Outlook!